# MS ACCESS order string column as Number and as String depending on his value

Tags: ms-access, sql-order-by

I have a column that can contain numbers and strings..and I need to order by a query by this column:

```
"Col1"
Cars
Bikes
1
2
25
3
4
41
5
```

But I Need:

```
"Col1"
Bikes
Cars
1
2
3
4
5
25
41
```

Is there a way to do this in MS access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *Val* which returns 0 for non-numeric strings:

```
Order By Val([Col1]), [Col1]
```